# Youtube api upload video.net

Tags: c#, .net, video, upload, youtube-data-api

Im trying to create a website from which you can upload videos from your device to youtube but be able to view those specific videos you uploaded form my site.(there's more purpose to it aswell)

Im using .net c# and I have my oauth keys and developer api keys, downloaded the json file etc. I downloaded the sample code google has for this but cant seem to get it working, not fully sure how it does work.

Could someone please help me out with this / explain it to me?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Video_Upload
/// </summary>
public class Video_Upload
{
    public Video_Upload()
    {
    //
    // TODO: Add constructor logic here

     new Video_Upload().Run().Wait();

}

private async Task Run()
{
    UserCredential credential;
    using (var stream = new FileStream("Client_id_googleApi.json",           FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
            // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
            new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None
        );
    }


    var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
    });

    //VIDEO INFO AND DETAILS

    var video = new Video();
    video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
    video.Snippet.Title = "Test Video 1";
    video.Snippet.Description = "Testing Video Upload";
    video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "Test", "First" };
    video.Snippet.CategoryId = "17";//category id for sport // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
    video.Snippet.ChannelId = "UCfvR-wqeoHmAGrHnoQRfs9w";
    video.Status = new VideoStatus();
    video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public"; // or "private" or "public"
    var filePath = @"C:\Users\siobhan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\FYP_November\GP010149.avi"; // Replace with path to actual movie file.

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
        videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
        videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

        await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
    }
    void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
{
        switch (progress.Status)
        {
            case UploadStatus.Uploading:
                Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesSent, " bytes sent.");
                break;

            case UploadStatus.Failed:
                Console.WriteLine("An error prevented the upload from completing.\n{0}", progress.Exception);
                break;
        }
    }
    void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video video)
{
        Console.WriteLine("Video id '{0}' was successfully uploaded.",         video.Id);
    }


    }



}
```

Comment: Not without *any* information about what code you're running or what isn't working, no.  Whatever you're pointing at on your screen, we can't see it.

Comment: not used to using this site, have uploaded code above

Comment: What is your specific question regarding this code?  In what way is it failing?  When you debug this, where/how specifically does it fail?

Comment: It says 'void cannot be used in this way' for both the void videosInsertRequest_progressChanged and _ResponseRecieved , when I go to see changes the error just dissapears, also says:
    CS0841 Cannot use local variable 'videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged' before it is declared

Comment: This code is filled with misaligned curly braces.  Fix the formatting and the problem should become clear.  You're trying to declare a method inside of a method, which isn't valid.

Comment: Yes perfect thank you!! been staring at this for too long to notice things like that!! thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It says 'void cannot be used in this way'

Because you're trying to declare a method inside of another method:

```
private async Task Run()
{
    //...

    void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
    {
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

This isn't valid in C#.  Methods are declared inside of a class and are essentially alongside each other.  Such as:

```
private async Task Run()
{
    //...
}

void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
{
    //...
}
```